# How to implement a fix bar layout in android

Tags: android

I want to create a layout like this:

[image]

I think the `ScrollView` is necessary, maybe like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="fixed">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Button...
            <ListView....
            <Button...
            </RelatievLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it seems that add a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` is not good idea.

Any idea to make it?

BTW, there are not only `Button1` and `Button2` outside the listview, there are more views, so I do not think add the views as foot or head is a good idea.

Comment: what do you have in listview?

Comment: A list of data searched from the server.

Comment: then why dont you use linerlayout instead of listview?

Comment: U mean add a `LinearLayout` and put the `ListView` inside it? If not, the data to be displayed are an `ArrayList`, is it proper to use the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: if you dont want to use ListView then you need add textview to Linearlayout and print the data in it.But why you dont want to use Listview?

Comment: I am sorry, but is it the general idea to use the `ListView` to show the list of data? Or can you give an example of show the list of data using `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Yes of course you can,it was designed for that purpose only

Comment: i will post an answer with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea (not recommanded): Adding a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` is a bad idea, because both are scrollable by default. You could use a `LinearLayout` instead of the `ListView` and create a custom onClickListener for the items.

```
<Scrollview>
   <Button.../>
   <LinearLayout>
     <items.../>
   </LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

Second idea (recommanded) is to go with one `ListView` and create a custom Adapter extending `BaseAdapter` returning the `Views` for each row and holding the data. This means adding your Buttons and Items to the `ListView` and create a custom `OnClickListener` and Adapter to hold you Model. This Is the way I have used and I would do it again this way.

I your Adapter, you will need to Override:

`getViewTypeCount` - number of types of different row-layouts.

`getItemViewType` the type of the row.

`getView` returning the view for a position, here you need to inflate the layout and set the data.

[This is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4777272/1515052) how to create a ListView with different types of rows.

Comment: In fact, I am using the second idea, I have my own adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter`,and I only override the `getView` method, I never use the `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`, I will have a try. But, the `button1` and `button2` in my example have nothing to do with the `listView`, so add them in the custom adapter is a good idea?

Comment: in this way the buttons are inside the scrollable are. Mixing different content is okay, if your adapter handles it correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rlt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code

```
LinearLayout llt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlt);
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        final int k =i;
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setId(i);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(" name:"+i);
        ll.addView(tv);
        ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("This is the printed text no"+k);
            }
        });
        //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    llt.addView(ll);
     }
```

You can create your own `ListView` like this