# Which is better for display list of data in android

Tags: android, listview

Suppose I have a list of items like this:

```
List<User> mPersonList=getAllUser();
```

Then I want to display them in the activity, I have two ideas:

1 Use the `ListView`

I will create a Custom adapter extending from `ArrayAdapter` to bind the data to the view. This this the general idea.

But sometimes, the parent of a `ListView` may(must) be a `ScrollView`, so someone [suggest me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20071916/306719) use the `Linearlayout`.

2 Use something like the `LinearLayout`.

Create one `LinearLayout` for each item, and add them to the parent view.

For example:

```
ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.xx):
for(Person p : mPersonList){
  LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(...) //created by constructor
  // or ll=mlayerInflate.inflate(R.layout.xxx);
  TextView tv=new TextView(..)
  tv.setText(p.name);
  ll.addView(tv);
  parent.addView(ll);
}
```

I wonder if which is better when performance considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` will be much better for performance than implementing the same in a `LinearLayout`.

The `ListView` will only inflate as many views as will fit on the screen at any one time. Inflating views is much more expensive than changing the values of a view, so this is much better.

EDIT:

However, you are right that if you are putting the `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` it will not work correctly. in that case you should probably use a `LinearLayout` instead, or perhaps re-work your layout so that you don't use the `ScrollView` parent (such as using `ListView` header views etc)

Comment: But how about if I have to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Definitely don't put a ListView inside a scrollview. It will collapse the ScrollView. I fought this one quite a bit early on. I generally add them to a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.